# How do I add \textit style at tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I have colorbox like this:

```
\newtcolorbox{note}{breakable,enhanced,colback=Khaki2!70,colframe=LavenderBlush2}
```

I want that the text at the body of the box will be *italic*, and I'm trying to find how what I need to add to the definition of `note` to make it.

Thank you!

Comment: @Sigur - Doesn't work.. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fontupper` option as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[breakable, skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{note}{breakable,enhanced,colback=Khaki2!70,colframe=LavenderBlush2, fontupper=\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{note}
some text
\end{note}
\end{document}
```